# Integral to periodic function.

Tags: periodic-functions

I have this question. 
I would like to help me with this problem please .
If $f'(x)$ is a periodic function, with period $a$, prove that $f(x)$ is a periodic function, if and only if $f(a)=f(0)$.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: It is given that $f'(x)$ is periodic.

Comment: if $f(x)$ is $a$-periodic then $f(x)+C$ is $a$-periodic, so the integration constant isn't the problem. An example of the problem is $f'(x) = 1$, to be compared with $f'(x) = \cos(2\pi x / a)$

Comment: and I prefer a more intuitive and explicit statement : if $g(x)$ is $a$-periodic, then there is a unique constant $\bar{g}$ such that $f(x) = \int_{x_0}^x (g(x)-\bar{g}) dx$ is $a$-periodic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $f(x)$ is periodic with period $a$ then $f(x) = f(x+a)$ for all x.
$f(0) = f(a)$
and $f'(x) = \lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {f(x+h) + f(x)}{h} = \lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {f(x+a + h) + f(x+a)}{h} = f'(x+a)$

To go the other direction.

It is a necessary condition that $f(0) = f(a)$ for $f(x)$ to be periodic.

but is $f'(x)$ periodic and $f(0) = f(a)$ sufficient?

$f(x+a) - f(x) = \int_x^{x+a} f'(x) dx$

Given that $f'(x)$ is periodic $\int_x^{x+a} f'(x) dx$ is constant.

$f(0) - f(a) \implies\int_0^{a} f'(x) dx = 0\\
f(x+a) = f(x)$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{equation}
\int_0^xf^\prime(t)\,dt=\int_a^{a+x}f^\prime(t)\,dt
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f(x)-f(0)=f(a+x)-f(a)
\end{equation}

So

\begin{equation}
f(x)=f(x+a)+f(0)-f(a)
\end{equation}